# Create objects on demand in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently optimizing MVC application, there are objects creating in `Controller Constructor`. Something like this

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private readonly GenericRepository<User> _user;
private readonly GenericRepository<UserDevice> _userDevice;
public UsersController()
{
    _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    _user = new GenericRepository<User>(_unitOfWork);
    _userDevice = new GenericRepository<UserDevice>(_unitOfWork);
}
```

This is simple example but actually there are a lot more objects creating in `Controller Constructor`, even there need only one object in `function` but other objects are creating as well. I want to implement a pattern where objects should create only on when needed.
One thing is in my mind to use `Abstract Factory Pattern` where all objects should create but I have no idea how to implement. You guys can suggest any other solution for the problem, using pattern is just my thought. Thanks

**Edit**
**On demand** means using object in a `method`, like I need only `_user` object then why is there `_userDevice` creating?

Comment: "objects should create only on when needed" -- where?  when?  Your question is not clear.  "When needed" is an ambiguous phrase to use because it could mean 1.) at a certain dime during execution or 2.) in your code in come place that doesn't get called in every code path but nevertheless is statically defined in the code.

Comment: If your class requires lots of objects, but only uses them occasionaly, it's likely violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). You might want to revisit your design, bearing the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles in mind. However, to actually answer your question, have you considered using [Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the objects only when they are actually required?

Comment: Are these objects expensive to create? Are you optimizing because you profiled your code?

Comment: @RB. Thanks, after your response I have searched about Lazy<T> and find it useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

```
private readonly Lazy<IUnitOfWork> _lazyUnitOfWork;

public UsersController()
{
    _layzUnitOfWork = new Lazy<IUnitOfWork>(() => new UnitOfWork());
}

// Instantiates the unit of work on first use
private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork { get { return _lazyUnitOfWork.Value; } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more thing, I'm thinking of remove all initializations from Controller, create an Abstract class and add all objects there with Lazy<T> and create concrete classes on that Abstract class. Is it good idea?

Comment: @AliShahbaz: I don't see a problem with that.